# CakePHP: Generate CakeEmail Template Output in Model

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a delayed email sending script. Whenever I schedule an email, I want to go ahead and place all of the information needed to send the email (to, subject, content, etc) in a database table. This is so that my email sending script can simply do 1 thing; send email. It doesn't have to bother with different views, setting the correct view vars, view vars, etc. Each template will have different view vars, and I don't want to have to deal with all of this in the sending email cron. So, let's say I want to schedule a welcome email:

```
// Schedule the welcome email from anywhere
$this->EmailLog->scheduleWelcomeEmail($member_id);

// EmailLog model
public function scheduleWelcomeEmail($member_id) {
    // lookup $member_id
    // uses 'welcome' template

    $data = array(
        'subject' => 'Welcome',
        'to' => $member['Member']['email'],
        'html' => // NEED RENDERED DATA FROM 'welcome' TEMPLATE
    );

    $this->create();
    $this->save($data);// SAVE the row - DO NOT actually send email
}
```

Then, a cron running in the background will simply grab the unsent email from the table row, set the appropriate parameters and send it.

So, how can I get the rendered view data, inside the model, saved in variable? Or, is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is wrong way to send email from Model In cakephp we can not access or render views in Models. So go with another approach and you can use cakephp shell to send email.
Below link you read for cakeshall

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)

[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)